# How can I use booleans in a Promise.all()

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, promise

I want to do something like this:

```
statusReady: boolean = false;
jobsReady: boolean = false;

ready() {
  return Promise.all([statusReady, jobsReady]);
}
```

...and the idea is basically so later I can do this:

```
this.ready().then(() => {
  // Do stuff here when we're all ready
});
```

If everything is already true, I'd expect the promise to resolve immediately, and if anything is false, it waits for the statuses to be true, then resolves. I'd use the ready() function anywhere in which I need to make sure certain pieces are finished loading.

Comment: No, because `satusReady` and `jobsReady` will be evaluated when you call `this.ready()`, and `Promise.all([false, false])` doesn't wait for them to be `true` - Promise.all does not work that way

Comment: You need to look at what is setting `statusReady` and `jobsReady` to `true`. Use a callback or promise there.

Comment: `Promise.all()` accepts an array of promises which means`statusReady` and `jobsReady` should either be promises or functions returning promises. If you have any event listeners to fire when the status and jobs are ready then you may promisify those event listeners and use as intended.

Answer (score 0):

So if I am correct, you're asking how to create a promise that resolves as soon as a list of booleans are all true?

I created a function that does exactly that. It takes an object of booleans as its only arg, and returns a promise that resolves as soon as they are all true.

Here is the function:

```
function whenBoolListIsTruePromise (boolList) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

        // Check if all values of boolList are already true
        var initializedAsTrue = true;
        Object.values(boolList).forEach(function (currentBoolValue) {
            if (!currentBoolValue) initializedAsTrue = false;
        }); 

        if (initializedAsTrue) {
            resolve();
        } else {

            // The following watches changes to any of the bools in the boolList, and resolves the promise when all are true.

            // 1. Copy boolList data to _actualData.
            // 2. For each key-value pair in boolList, change it to a :set and :get property that accesses _actualData.
            // 3. Every time a set is run, check if everything in actual data is now true. If it is, resolve promise.

            var _actualData = Object.assign({}, boolList); 
            Object.entries(boolList).forEach(function ([boolName, boolValue]) {
                Object.defineProperty(boolList, boolName, {
                    configurable: true,
                    set: function (newV) {
                        var allTrue = true;
                        _actualData[boolName] = newV;
                        Object.values(_actualData).forEach(function (currentBoolValue) {
                            if (!currentBoolValue) allTrue = false;
                        });

                        if (allTrue) {
                            // Remove :set and :get, bringing back to a regular simple object
                            Object.entries(_actualData).forEach(function ([boolName2, boolValue2]) {
                                Object.defineProperty(boolList, boolName2, {
                                    configurable: true,
                                    value: boolValue2,
                                });
                            });

                            resolve();
                        }
                    },

                    get: function () {
                        return _actualData[boolName];
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    });
}
```

You use this function by creating an object of booleans and passing it as an argument for this function. This function will return a promise that resolves when all of those booleans are set to true.

```
var myBoolList = {"statusReady": false, "jobsReady": false};

whenBoolListIsTruePromise(myBoolList).then(function () {
    console.log("All values are now true!");
}, function (error) {
    console.error(error);
});

myBoolList.statusReady = true;
myBoolList.jobsReady = true;
```

Here is a working example for you to look at:

```js
function whenBoolListIsTruePromise (boolList) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

        // Check if all values of boolList are already true
        var initializedAsTrue = true;
        Object.values(boolList).forEach(function (currentBoolValue) {
            if (!currentBoolValue) initializedAsTrue = false;
        }); 
        
        if (initializedAsTrue) {
            resolve();
        } else {

            // The following watches changes to any of the bools in the boolList, and resolves the promise when all are true.
            
            // 1. Copy boolList data to _actualData.
            // 2. For each key-value pair in boolList, change it to a :set and :get property that accesses _actualData.
            // 3. Every time a set is run, check if everything in actual data is now true. If it is, resolve promise.
            
            var _actualData = Object.assign({}, boolList); 
            Object.entries(boolList).forEach(function ([boolName, boolValue]) {
                Object.defineProperty(boolList, boolName, {
                    configurable: true,
                    set: function (newV) {
                        var allTrue = true;
                        _actualData[boolName] = newV;
                        Object.values(_actualData).forEach(function (currentBoolValue) {
                            if (!currentBoolValue) allTrue = false;
                        });

                        if (allTrue) {
                            // Remove :set and :get, bringing back to a regular simple object
                            Object.entries(_actualData).forEach(function ([boolName2, boolValue2]) {
                                Object.defineProperty(boolList, boolName2, {
                                    configurable: true,
                                    value: boolValue2,
                                });
                            });
                            
                            resolve();
                        }
                    },
                    
                    get: function () {
                        return _actualData[boolName];
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    });
}

var myBoolList = {"statusReady": false, "jobsReady": false};

whenBoolListIsTruePromise(myBoolList).then(function () {
    console.log("All values are now true!");
}, function (error) {
    console.error(error);
});

myBoolList.statusReady = true;
myBoolList.jobsReady = true;
```

This function works by creating :set and :get accessors for each key in the boolList object. The :set function is ran whenever any of the things in the booList object are set (changed). I have made it so the :set function checks if all of the booleans are true, and resolves the promise if they are.

Here is a helpful article I found that talks a bit about :get and :set
https://javascriptplayground.com/es5-getters-setters/

Answer (score -3):

You can not use boolean in Promise.all() method. The [article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)  in the MDN clearly state that only promise iterable can be passed in Promise.all() method.

Instead you can use two more Promises which will resolve when the value is true. In your code snippet I did not understand how those 2 value gonna change to true. If you can post how those 2 values gonna change I think we will help you to shape the code properly.

Comment: If you specify why down vote it will help me in future to answer questions more accurately. Thanks...

Comment: You’re being downvoted because you didn’t answer the question. You just cut and pasted a definition that is related to the problem.